# NullReferenceException when defining a custom object in ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, templatebinding

I'm trying to create a custom Context Menu as a user control. The code behind for this user control looks like this:

```
public partial class UCContextMenu : UserControl
{
    private List<ContextMenuItem> m_menuItems = new List<ContextMenuItem>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public List<ContextMenuItem> Items
    {
        get { return m_menuItems; }
        set { m_menuItems = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler Command;
}
```

Then, I defined the `ContextMenuItem` type **in the same namespace** as the user control (in the same file actually) which is essentially a menu item:

```
public class ContextMenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The `ascx` page for the user control includes a `repeater` control which is defined like this:

```
<div id="contentHolder">
    <ul id="ulContextMenu" style="display: none; z-index: 1000; border-width: 0.8px;
        font-size: 13px;" class="ui-corner-all">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# Items %>">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><a href='#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %></a>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And finally to use it in a page after registering it, I have:

```
<uc:ContextMenu runat="server" OnCommand="SomeMethod">
    <Items>
       <uc:ContextMenuItem Name="SomeName" Text="SomeText" />
    </Items>
</uc:ContextMenu>
```

Now when I run this, I get a `NullReference` parse error on line

```
<uc:ContextMenuItem Name="SomeName" Text="SomeText" />
```

When not running, Visual Studio also says `Element 'ContextMenuItem' is not a known element.` It doesn't catch the exception at runtime either so maybe that way I could look at the stack trace to see what's going on. I was just wondering if anyone has encountered similar issues like this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `UCContextMenu` inherits `UserControl`. `ContextMenuItem` does not. Does that matter?

Comment: It doesn't inherit from `UserControl` because it's NOT a user control. It's a container class.

Comment: It looks like a normal old class to me. It seems like it should be inheriting something or decorated in some way identifying it as a container class.

Comment: What should it inherit from though? All the similar codes I've seen are just plain classes with no inheritance.

Comment: Check http://forums.asp.net/p/1552731/3811467.aspx as it may apply...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Already did. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Create `ContextMenuItem` as a normal user control. The fact that you are defining it in the same namespace as you have emphasized doesn't help you in any way.
So, just add ContextMenuItem.ascx to your project and then [register and add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sbz9etab(v=vs.100).aspx) the control on page or other control.

Comment: I shouldn't have to make `ContextMenuItem` a user control though.